# Where can I find Google Admob Ad unit ID in APK?

Tags: android, admob, ads

It's not in res/value/strings.xml so can anyone tell where else it would be or where can I look for it pls help it will be great help to me and if there is any way of hiding it or another way by which it can't be in code tell me.

Comment: Stealing and using someone's admob ad unit id is a crime

Comment: Actually I bought the app and he told me just change the ad mob I'd and app id with mine and upload it but I can't find it that's why I'm asking

Comment: Do you have source code?

Comment: 1) You can contact developer.
2) Strings folder
3) Manifest file check app id.
4) You have to manually check all java or kotlin classes. where ads have been displayed.

Not only you have to change Admob ads unit id also App id which is in manifest..

Answer (score 0):

It is usualy located in the AndroidLauncher (android -> java -> com.xxx.xxx -> AndroidLauncher). If it is not, then you should just search the project for "ca-app-pub" as this is how the App unit ID starts with. You can do this by going to `Edit > Find > Find in path…` and type in "ca-app-pub" and it should find the location.